# Notification sound does not work in flutter flutter_local_notifications

Tags: android, flutter, android-notifications, flutter-dependencies, flutter-local-notification

```
Future scheduleAlarmWithSound(Task task) async {
    final exists = await _checkIfAlreadyScheduled(task.id);
    if (exists) return;

    var scheduleNotificationDateTime =
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(task.endTime);
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('v1', 'Todo', 'Reminder',
            icon: 'icon',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('icon'),
            sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('annoyingalarm'),
            playSound: true,
            showWhen: true);
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
        task.id,
        task.task,
        'Time\'s up!\n Did you completed the task?\nIf not better luck next time.',
        scheduleNotificationDateTime,
        platformChannelSpecifics);
    print("Alarm scheduled with sound");
  }

  Future scheduleAlarmWithoutSound(Task task) async {
    final exists = await _checkIfAlreadyScheduled(task.id);
    if (exists) return;

    var scheduleNotificationDateTime =
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(task.endTime);
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('v1', 'Todo', 'Reminder',
            icon: 'icon',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('icon'),
            playSound: false,
            showWhen: true);
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
        task.id,
        task.task,
        'Time\'s up! Did you completed the task?',
        scheduleNotificationDateTime,
        platformChannelSpecifics);
    print("Alarm scheduled without sound");
  }
```

First of all, let me explain my program. It's a reminder app. If we click remind me button then a notification with an alarm sound will be set else a notification without an alarm sound will be set. There is also an option for altering this decision in future. The problem is that when I set a reminder with an alarm sound notification, the sound is not played. But the sound is played if there is no function for setting an alarm without sound.

Comment: Are you sure your sound resource is being referenced correctly? Because you mentioned that the native sound is functioning.

Comment: Yes, it is and it is the notification sound if I don't have the function scheduleAlarmWithoutSound.